# Invoking apply(String.t .....) in Elixir

Tags: elixir

How can I call a method of a module given the name of a module as a string? I know how to use apply. How can I use it the name of a module being a string?

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the string to the atom. All Elixir modules live in `Elixir` namespace (basically to prevent name clash,) hence atoms, denoting Elixir modules, are all starting with `"Elixir."`:

```
iex(1)> defmodule M, do: def foo, do: IO.puts "BAR"
iex(2)> name = "M"
iex(3)> apply(String.to_atom("Elixir." <> name), :foo, [])
BAR
```

Comment: Just to clarify - I don't think you need `String.to_atom("Elixir." <> name)`, module name is properly converted to this form anyway!

Comment: @PawełDawczak I am not sure I follow. Module name is, but `String.to_atom("M")` returns `:M`, not `M` which is essentially handled by the compiler and converted to `Elixir.M`. Here we have no compiler on hand.

Comment: My point was, I don't think you need to do this: `apply(String.to_atom("Elixir." <> name), :foo, [])`, as this would work just fine: `apply(M, :foo, [])`, like: `apply(Kernel, :+, [1, 2])
# => 3`

Answer (score 0):

Elixir modules, when used and printed, omit the `Elixir.` leading part from their name. When both Elixir and Erlang modules are compiled, they generate a beam file. This prefix is required in order to avoid name collisions for Elixir and Erlang with the same name.

When you write and read code you don't have to think about this as it is automatically handled. Note that both the left and the right sides are atoms. The quotes are needed to handle special symbols and modules are just atoms starting with a capital letter and as a syntax sugar the `:` can be omitted in this case.

```
iex(1)> :"Elixir.SomeModule" == SomeModule
true
iex(2)> :"Elixir.SomeModule" == Elixir.SomeModule
true
```

As the compiler handles these prefixes automatically for you, it would be advisable to let the compiler handle the prefixes when you convert a string to a module name as well.

This can be done by using `Module.concat/1` and `Module.safe_concat/1`. The difference between them is that the first one uses `binary_to_atom/2` and the second one uses `binary_to_existing_atom/2` to convert the string to an atom. Atoms are not garbage collected so it is dangerous to let random user input be provided as an argument to `binary_to_atom/2` or its Elixir equivalent `String.to_atom/1` as this can lead to a VM crash. In this particular use case you would run into errors if you try to call a function from a module that does not exist.

Knowing this, the `Module.safe_concat/1` function is the most appropriate because:

- It lets the compiler handle the `Elixir.` prefix.
- It cannot crash the VM by reaching the limit of atoms allowed on a node.
- It would generate an error in case the string you provided does not correspond to an existing module.

Success case:

```
iex(1)> Module.safe_concat(["String"]).upcase("xyz")        
"XYZ"
```

Raise an error when there is a typo in the module name:

```
iex(2)> Module.safe_concat(["Strign"]).upcase("xyz")
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_existing_atom("Elixir.Strign", :utf8)
    (elixir 1.12.0-dev) src/elixir_aliases.erl:126: :elixir_aliases.safe_concat/1
```